# Failed to call standard math function inside debugger?

Tags: ubuntu, math, gcc, gdb, symbols

I tried to call my own function and standard function in debugger:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int i=3;
void f(){
  ++i;
  printf("%d\n",i);
}
int main(){
  ++i;
  int j=i+2;
  double d=cos(0.0);
  printf("%f\n",d);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile this program and run, it will print "1.000000" as I expected.
In gdb, I tried:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40055b: file x.c, line 10.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/x/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at x.c:10
10    ++i;
(gdb) call f()
4
(gdb) call f()
5
(gdb) call cos(0.0)
No symbol "cos" in current context.  # WHY?????
(gdb) call printf("%d\n",i)
5
$1 = 2
(gdb) call putchar('a')
$2 = 97
```

Why gdb cannto even find symbol? I suppose "-g" option will bring debug information for both my program and standard library, right? Or do I have to install extra package for debugging/source code for standard library? I'm on ubuntu16.04

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite immediate appearances, this part of gdb works well.  So my first instinct is that we're in some sort of GIGO situation -- gdb is unusually susceptible to the enemy action of compilers and kernels -- and some investigation is required.

You don't say if you are using C or C++.

In C++, I can see that there is no debuginfo emitted for `cos`, and the call is completely optimized away.  You can check this by running `nm` and noting that `cos` doesn't appear as an undefined symbol; or simply by  noticing that this program links just fine without `-lm`.

My theory for C++ is that this happens because there is a `constexpr` version of `cos` in scope (I see it in the preprocessed output but I didn't try to really verify), and so g++ optimizes away the entire call.

For C, I see the same thing by default.  However, I can get a call to `cos` by passing `-fno-builtin-cos` to gcc.  But, haha, it still isn't in the debuginfo!

That seems like a gcc bug to me.  Normally you do not need debuginfo for a library just to have access to a type or function from the library that your program uses.

You can also notice that something weird is going on by trying to print the function itself:

```
(gdb) p cos
$1 = {<text gnu-indirect-function variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff7aebc50 <cos>
```

This is doubly bad news, because "GNU indirect" functions are magical creatures not always understood properly by gdb.  In particular I don't think they can be called from the debugger, even with the debuginfo installed.

In fact, the only thing I could make work was to take the address of `cos` in the program, then call via that pointer, like:

```
mumble *my_cos = &cos;
...
(gdb) print my_cos(0.0)
```

Well, that's not completely true.  I could also make this work:

```
(gdb) info func cos@plt
All functions matching regular expression "cos@plt":

Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000000400500  cos@plt
(gdb) p ((double(*)(double))0x0000000000400500)(0.0)
$6 = 1
```

This avoids the GNU indirect stuff.  However, it's quite unpleasant.

Comment: Thanks, your reply is to the point. You could see from gdb print, I'm using "x.c" file, which is not C++. Well at first I was wondering why I can compile it without -lm, now I know it's being replaced by built-in functions of gcc. When specified -fno-builtin, it requires -lm.

Answer (score 0):

- cos function is implemented in libm, not libc. Did you even link with -lm?
- Compiler optimizes away constant expressions. There is no reason to calculate cos(0) at run-time. So there is no need for cos function to be included and no reason for math library to be linked. Reference to libm is removed from your executable (which you can verify with readelf or similar tool), hence gdb known nothing about cos (or any other function from math library).
- As Tom Tromey explained, one possible workaround is to disable gcc's built-in functions. After this i can call cos from gdb (like this:print cos(1.0)).